# Replace H330 with H730 controller in Dell T130 server

Tags: dell-poweredge, raid-controller

We carelessly sold a Dell T130 server with a H330 controller to a customer who wanted an as cheap as possible soultion.

Due to performace issues he is asking now to replace the H330 controller with a R730 controller.

Dell support tells me that that the controller can be replaced except the cable for the HDD LED which isn't available as "after sales product".

Has anyobody done this before and can confirm that the other cables fit?

Can the LED cable be replaced with a regular 2pin cable? like [this cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HNWPTDQ)

Comment: Contact your Dell representative to validate, it's two distinct department at Dell, as the support got inventory that they can't use for normal sell and will never offer it, but the rep can check on their side.